# MySQL Join Where association does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I get customer ids for customers with sites that have appointments in 2011

```
SELECT customers.id
FROM customers 
INNER JOIN sites ON customers.id = sites.customer_id
INNER JOIN appointments ON appointments.site_id = sites.id
WHERE YEAR(appointments.day) = 2011
```

I'm looking to get customers who don't have any appointments in 2011. Confused on how to go about it.

Comment: Do the customers link to the appointments directly at all? For example, is there a customer_id in Appointments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of ways:

```
SELECT
    C.id
FROM
    Customers C
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            Sites S
        INNER JOIN Appointments A ON
            A.site_id = S.id AND
            YEAR(A.day) = 2011
        WHERE
            S.customer_id = C.id
    )
```

or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    C.id
FROM
    Customers C
INNER JOIN Sites S ON
    S.customer_id = C.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Appointments A ON
    A.site_id = S.id AND
    YEAR(A.day) = 2011
WHERE
    A.id IS NULL
```

Comment: is the left join to Sites required?

Comment: No, I suppose that it could be an INNER JOIN. I'll change that as the INNER JOIN will probably perform better in some cases. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

...WHERE NOT YEAR(appointments.day) = 2011

Comment: That would actually work :) `WHERE NOT (appointments.day BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-12-31')` would be faster, because it allows to use an index.

Answer (score 0):

Should have done an answer instead of an edit.  Don't really want to look for NULL's due to scaling.

```
SELECT id
FROM customers 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sites 
                      INNER JOIN appointments ON appointments.site_id = sites.id
                  WHERE sites.customer_id = customers.id AND YEAR(appointments.day) = 2011)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT customers.id
 FROM customers, sites, appointments
 WHERE (customers.id = sites.customer_id and appointments.id = sites.id) 
 and  YEAR(appointments.day) <> 2011
```

Please check your specific database server for "<>" which is "not equal".